# Rails 4.2 Autoloading not thread-safe

Tags: multithreading, ruby-on-rails-4, eager-loading

I have the following model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  def send_message(content)
    MessagePoro.new(content).deliver!
  end

  def self.send_to_all(content)
    threads = []
    all.each do |user|
      threads << Thread.new do
        user.send_message(content)
      end
    end
    threads.each(&:join)
  end
end
```

MessagePoro model can be something simple, e.g. app/models/message_poro.rb:

```
class MessagePoro
  def initialize(content)
    # ...
  end

  def deliver!
    # ...
  end
end
```

Now, when I'm having e.g. 100 Users, and I'm running User.send_to_all("test") I'm **sometimes** getting thoser errors:

```
RuntimeError: Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant MessagePoro
```

or:

```
wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)
```

I figured it must be because MessagePoro isn't loaded and all Threads try to load it simultaneously, or something like that. Since those errors occur only sometimes, I'm pretty sure it's only when there is a 'race condition' or has something todo with Threading. I have tried to initialize MessagePoro before starting the Threads, and I have played around with eager_loading, but the problem seems to persist.
What else can I try to mitigate this issue?

Comment: try to require it manually before autoloading

Comment: Could you please elaborate? Like calling MessagePoro.new before the threads are starting?
In case this is fixing it, I'm still curious about the underlying issue

Comment: no. currently you have the basic Rails Autoloading Setup. If you first call MessagePoro somethere in the code it will require it accordingly to some convention(e.g MyModule::MessagePoro should be within autoload_path/my_module/message_poro.rb). but you can try to require it manually require 'path/to/message_poro'.

Comment: What ruby verions are u using?

Comment: I'm facing the same issues with eager_loading, Ruby 2.1 and Rails 4.1 and 4.2

Answer (score 10):

I recently ran into a very similar issue when trying to use an extra custom library placed in the `[rails_root]/lib` directory.

## TL;DR:

You can use eager loading to around the issue, as that makes sure all constants/modules/classes are in memory before any actual code runs. However for this to work:

1. You must have `config.eager_load = true` set in the Rails config (this is done by default in the Production environment)
2. The file that your class-to-be-eager-loaded is in must be in the `config.eager_load_paths`, as opposed to `config.autoload_paths`.

OR

You can use `require` or `require_dependency` (another ActiveSupport feature) to make sure the code you need it explicitly loaded before it would otherwise get autoloaded by Rails.

## More info

As digidigo mentioned in his reply, the circular dependency error comes from the `ActiveSupport::Dependencies` module, or the **Rails autoloader** in more general terms. This code is **not threadsafe**, as it uses that class/module variable to store files that it is loading. If two threads end up autoloading the same thing at the same time, one of them can get mislead by seeing the file to load already in that class variable and throwing a 'circular dependency' error.

I ran into this issue when running Rails in production mode with the (threaded) Puma webserver. We had added a small library to the `lib` directory in our Rails root, and initially added `lib` to `config.autoload_once_paths`. Everything was fine in Development, but in Production (with `config.eager_load` and `config.cache_classes` enabled), very occasionally we would get these same circular dependency issues with near-simultaneous requests. A few hours of debugging later, I ended up seeing the non-thread-safety happening in front of my eyes, when stepping through the ActiveSupport code around the circular dependency and seeing the different threads pick up at different points in the code. The first thread would add the file to load into the `loading` array, then the second thread would find it there and raise the circular dependency error.

It turns out adding something to `autoload_paths` or `autoload_once_paths` does *NOT* also mean that it will get picked up by eager loading. However the opposite is true - paths added to `eager_load_paths` will be considered for autoloading if eager_load is disabled (see [this article](http://blog.arkency.com/2014/11/dont-forget-about-eager-load-when-extending-autoload/) for more info). We switched to `eager_load_paths` and have had no further issues so far.

Interestingly enough, just before the Rails 4 beta, autoloading was disabled in the Production environment by default, which meant that an issue like this would have caused a hard fail 100% of the time, rather than a quirky threading fail 5% of the time. However this was reverted in time for the 4.0 beta release - you can see some (passionate) discussion about it [here](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/13142) (including the choice phrase 'honestly, you're telling me to go f*** myself?'). Since then though, that revert has been reverted ahead of the Rails 5.0.0beta1, so hopefully less people will have to deal with this headache of an issue again in the future.

## Extra notes:

The Rails autoloader is totally separate from the Ruby autoloader - this seems to be because Rails does more inference on directory structure when trying to autoload constants.

Ruby's autoload appears to have been made threadsafe as of Ruby 2.0, however this has nothing to do with the Rails autoloading code. Rails's autoloader appears to be definitely **not** threadsafe, as previously mentioned.

Comment: I believe I'm having to deal with this threading issue in Rails trying to autoload controllers. Aside from eager loading in development, how can I require or require_dependency for controllers in Api::V1? Please read this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62927007/rails-autoload-issue-after-installing-sidekiq-argumenterror-a-copy-of-apiv1

Answer (score 2):

This isn't really an answer but I do have more information.  The error being thrown is from ActiveSupport

```
 if file_path
    expanded = File.expand_path(file_path)
    expanded.sub!(/\.rb\z/, '')

    if loading.include?(expanded)
      raise "Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant #{qualified_name}"
    else
      require_or_load(expanded, qualified_name)
      raise LoadError, "Unable to autoload constant #{qualified_name}, expected #{file_path} to define it" unless from_mod.const_defined?(const_name, false)
      return from_mod.const_get(const_name)
    end
  elsif mod = autoload_module!(from_mod, const_name, qualified_name, path_suffix)
    return mod
  elsif
```

Upon further research we can see that loading is a class variable.

```
# Stack of files being loaded.
mattr_accessor :loading
self.loading = []
```

Two threads checking the same file:

First thread hits this code and puts a path into loading

```
      loading << expanded
```

Then second thread goes to check the path represented by expanded and hits

```
 if loading.include?(expanded)
      raise "Circular dependency detected while autoloading constant #{qualified_name}"
```

What am I missing?  ActiveSupport::Dependencies is not threadsafe?

Answer (score 0):

After some research it turns out, that autoload is thread-safe now. So it is propbably a regression. Checkout [Threading with the AWS SDK for Ruby](https://ruby.awsblog.com/post/Tx16QY1CI5GVBFT/Threading-with-the-AWS-SDK-for-Ruby). The patch was introduced by Charles Nutter in ruby 2.0.0 [autoload is not thread-safe](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/921)

Anyway if it is only this class, you can avoid autoloading it by requiring it manually.
Just require it manually.

```
require 'message_poro'
class User
def self.send_to_all(content) 
  ... 
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. I understand that your fix cures the symptoms, but I feel like this doesn't address the underlying issue

Comment: It does actuallly as it dumps autoloading :), which is the underlying issue

Comment: Plz post your ruby Version and lets submit a Bug request to Rails or ruby. Would be also nice if you can create a Demo github Repo to repriduce the bug

Comment: The Circular dependency error is being thrown by ActiveSupport and is not a ruby issue.  And it looks to me that it is still not threadsafe.